# jQuery tab key event on soft keyboard for iOS 7 devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to capture the tab key event, through jQuery, when a user is on the soft keyboard of an iOS 7 device?

**Update**

Here is some basic code I am using. The left and right "focus" arrows on the iOS soft keyboard do not trigger a keydown event at all:

```
$("input").on("keydown", function (event) {
    // console.log("keydown detected");
    if (event.which === 9) {
        // console.log("tab key down detected");

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the basic code that you are using that is not working?

Comment: Do you mean prev / next keys? I've made an initial version of a plugin which detects those: https://github.com/zvona/Servant.js. Check at least the source code in order to understand how to capture those.

Comment: @epascarello code sample added.

Comment: @zvona I mean the prev / next "focus" arrows for input elements. I will take a look at your source code. Thanks for the heads up and link.

Comment: @Troy - that's what I meant. They used to be labeled as "prev" and "next". The core idea is to create data-custom-index and then to compare whether we're moving (onfocus) to an element with higher or lower index.